# html div accepts focus when tabbing through but not when set via javascript

Tags: javascript, html

On my page (Blazor server) I have a div on which I want to be able to set focus through javascript but I can't get it to work. I have tabindex="0" set on the div, and it will focus if I tab through the application but it doesn't work through javascript. The crazy thing is I had this working a while back but for the life of me I can't figure out what changed that caused this to stop working. Here's my javascript function. I've verified through the console that the element id being sent in is correct. Any ideas on what I might look for?

```
function setFocus(elementId) {
    this.console.warn("Setting focus to element " + elementId)
    const element = document.getElementById(elementId);
    if (element) {
        element.focus();
        this.console.warn("Focus set to element " + elementId)
    }
    else {
        this.console.warn("setFocus could not find element " + elementId)
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't [reproduce the issue](https://jsfiddle.net/6tuah7jw/). Make sure you haven't styled the div so, that it doesn't show it has gained the focus, and the warnings are not filtered out from the console output.

Comment: Thanks for your response. If it were styled such that it wasn't showing focus, wouldn't that also be an issue when tabbing through the app? In that case it does in fact show the focus. And I do see the messages in the console that it found the element and put focus to it, however it's just not showing focus.

Comment: [Not reproducable either](https://jsfiddle.net/6tuah7jw/1/) ..?

Comment: Ah ha! Your CSS did it. Clearly you were on the right track with my styling causing an issue. I'm still not sure what specifically I have that's causing this but when I used your focusable class it started working. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Maybe it's an external stylesheet you've added lately? Notice, that I saw the native "focus border" on my first example too. You can check which CSS rules are applied to that div by inspecting the element with the DevTools.

Comment: I've been digging around dev tools trying to figure out what it is, but one thing I did discover is that the native focus border is affected by whether dev tools is displayed or not (at least in Chrome). Just some funkiness there but with your focusable class it works no matter what so I'll go with that. Thanks again!